# What parameters are missing when I use this function? Python, Pytest

Tags: python, testing, pytest, functional-testing

I am trying to call a function to use it result in parametrize. I use fixtures in this function and when I call it at the class level, I see an error.
My code:

```
    def subscriber_groups_ID(self, init_http_session, init_util):
        # get sub group
        response = init_http_session.get("/api/subscriberGroups", headers={"Authorization": init_util.auth_main_token()})
        subcriberGroupID = response.json()["subscriberGroups"][0]["subscriberGroupID"]

        return subcriberGroupID



subscriberGroupID = subscriber_groups_ID()
    json = [
            ({ "subscriberGroupID": subscriberGroupID, "subscriberTariffTypeID": "0"}),
            ({ "subscriberGroupID": subscriberGroupID, "subscriberTariffTypeID": Util.generate_tariff(Util)})
]
```

and error

```
TypeError: TestSubscribers.subscriber_groups_ID() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'self', 'init_http_session', and 'init_util'
```

Whats wrong and how to call it correct?

I try to use other ways and make this function in Utils class, but it not helps

Comment: You need an instance of the corresponding class, say `obj`, and then call it like `obj.subscriber_groups_ID(session,util)`.

Answer (score 1):

> `subscriberGroupID = subscriber_groups_ID()`

You called it with zero arguments.

Call it with `self`, and then whatever `init_http_session` and `init_util` you have.

Comment: It not works for me, cause I have another error with request method AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'